# Let $X$ be $\mathbb{C}$ with the following topology: A subset $F$ of $X$ is closed $\iff$ $F$ is the set of zero(s) of a polynomial. Connected?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{C}$ with the following topology: A subset $F$ of $X$ is closed $\iff$ $F$ is the set of zero(s) of a polynomial.

Is $X$ Compact? Connected?

$X$ is indeed Compact. If $\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $X$, then the complement of each one is finite. Thus we can take one to cover all but a finitely many points of $X$, and then choose a finite number of elements of the cover to achieve a finite cover.

As for it being connected... A space $X$ is connected $\iff$ there is no continuous onto map $f: X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.

I think there does not exist such a continuous map... To have the inverse image of both $0$ and $1$ be open would mean that both of their preimages have finite complements, which is not possible. $\therefore X$ is connected.

Comment: This is an odd way to specify the [Cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology).

Comment: It's not all that odd. It's like a baby version of the Zariski topology.

Comment: Possibly confusing terminology note: the "every cover has a finite sub-cover" definition of compactness is sometimes called quasi-compactness, where "compact" means "quasi-compact and hausdorff".  For my personal taste, this is just confusing, but it is common, especially in algebriac geometry, which is where one is likely to see topologies like the one you defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another proof.

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be any two (nonempty) open sets in this topology, with complements $F_1$ and $F_2$. Since

$$U_1 \cap U_2= \mathbb{C} \setminus (F_1 \cup F_2)$$

and because $F_1$ and $F_2$ are finite, this intersection cannot be empty. Therefore, *no two open sets can ever be disjoint*. This proves that the given topology is both connected and non-Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $X$ is the union of the non empty disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$,  the complementary of $U$ is $V$, which is also closed, thus $V$ is finite, similarly $U$ is closed since it is the complementary subset of $V$ so it is finite contradiction since $\mathbb{C}$ is not finite.